# Android: Issue in getting a list of all installed apps including system apps

Tags: android

I have a `listview` which show the all installed apps including some system apps but does not show gallery, contact, messages apps. Please tell me how can I get all these system apps. Here is my code

```
public static List getInstalledApplication(Context c)
    {
       // return c.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

        List<ApplicationInfo> installedApps = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
        PackageManager pm = c.getPackageManager();
        List<ApplicationInfo> apps = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

        for(ApplicationInfo app : apps) {
            //checks for flags; if flagged, check if updated system app
            if((app.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP) == 1) {
                installedApps.add(app);
                //it's a system app, not interested
            } else if ((app.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1) {
                //Discard this one
                //in this case, it should be a user-installed app
              //  installedApps.add(app);
            } else {
                installedApps.add(app);
            }
        }
        return installedApps;
    }
```

Tell me where I make mistake. Help me with some code.

Comment: some system apps means? do you want any specific apps?

Comment: @SathishKumarJ some apps like contact,message,gallery,calculator i want to like show those apps which show in my mobile manu

Answer (score 1):

The apps that you want to list (Gallery, Message, etc) are written in system partition and hence, `(app.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1)` will be true.

```
FLAG_SYSTEM
if set, this application is installed in the device's system image.
```

Thats why the apps that you want to also list are getting skipped.

If you want to get apps which are listed in your launcher i.e apps with category `<Launcher>` get the list using following code

```
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfos = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    // using hashset so that there will be no duplicate packages, 
    // if no duplicate packages then there will be no duplicate apps
    HashSet<ApplicationInfo> installedApps = new HashSet<ApplicationInfo>(0);

    // getting package names and adding them to the hashset
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfos) {
        installedApps.add(resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
    }
```

Comment: @faisal : I think this answer might help you

Comment: i can not understand your answer please describe some more or edit my code please

Comment: for eg : Gallery is a system app. And it is not getting listed because it is getting skipped as you are skipping the non updated system apps

Comment: Question : Which type of apps do you want to list?

Comment: ok how can i get app like contact message , gallery, calculator apps

Comment: try following code instaed of the 2nd if block
else if ((app.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1) { installedApps.add(app);
            }
You will get all apps that were missing

Comment: BUT i do not want all apps

Comment: i only want some system apps which show me in launcher not other apps which not show on mobile

Comment: @Neji when i use this its give error in my adapter ResolveInfo can not be cast

Comment: have updated the code, check now. This should complete your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to show all the installed apps. You could get rid of the if-else block in your code and simply add all the apps and display them.
or make these change in you code

1) Fetch all the apps by this code.

```
List<ApplicationInfo> apps = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
```

2) And separate system apps from user installed with the following code:

```
List<ApplicationInfo> apps = getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(0);
for(ApplicationInfo app : apps) {
    if((app.flags & (ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP | ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)) > 0) {
        // It is a system app
    } else {
        // It is installed by the user
    }
}
```

Comment: i do not want to get all system apps

Answer (score 0):

Try this different ways.

//First

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
```

// Second

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages)
{
  Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
  Log.d(TAG, "Launch Activity :" + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName)); 
}
```

// Third

```
private List getInstalledComponentList()
        throws NameNotFoundException {
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List ril = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
    List componentList = new ArrayList();
    String name = null;

    for (ResolveInfo ri : ril) {
        if (ri.activityInfo != null) {
            Resources res = getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(ri.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
            if (ri.activityInfo.labelRes != 0) {
                name = res.getString(ri.activityInfo.labelRes);
            } else {
                name = ri.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(
                        getPackageManager()).toString();
            }
            componentList.add(name);
        }
    }
    return componentList;
 }
```